# Multiply 2 colums of gridview and display the result in a new

Tags: c#, mysql

I need multiply column valorprod * cantidad and display a new colum with name subtotal

[image]

the code is here

```
 DataTable dsDetalle = new DataTable("Data");
 using (MySqlCommand commandSql = cn.CreateCommand())
 {
      commandSql.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      commandSql.CommandText = "select * from detalle where idVenta=@idVenta and idlocal=@idlocal";
      commandSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idVenta", txt_boleta.Text);
      commandSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idlocal", txtlocal.Text);
      MySqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(commandSql);
      sqlAdapter.Fill(dsDetalle);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a calculate column on the fly.

```
commandSql.CommandText = @"
   SELECT  *, ( valorprod * cantidad ) AS subtotal
   FROM    detalle
   WHERE   idVenta = @idVenta AND idlocal = @idlocal";
```